# Method to determine of coordinates in GeoJSON feature are Lat/Lng or UTM?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, utm, turf

Is there a `@turf` or any other helper method to quickly determine if coordinates in GeoJSON feature are Lat/Lng  or UTM?

Comment: Look for a CRS element in the GeoJSON, but "spec" GeoJSON will be lon/lat by definition

Comment: If all coordinates are between -180 and 180 they are likely as long-lat (never Lat/Lng).

Comment: So that's what `crs` property stands for! Thanks.

Comment: crs has been removed , http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/geojsonio/vignettes/geojson_spec.html  read section CRS (Coordinate Reference System)